# Iphone's retina display in the simulator

Tags: iphone, ios4, points

I'm getting a bit confused on how to use the simulator to build applications that need to support the new higher resolution of the iphone 4.

I would except when selecting the iphone4 simulator to run the app on that `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` would give me 960x640 back, but instead it still giving me the old resolution (480x320) ?

Although the iphone4 simulator appears as a giant phone on my screen, it appears that it still consists of only 480x320 pixels. For instance when I would want to display something on line 700, it'll just fall ofscreen ?

Thanks for any input on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UIScreen has a new `scale` method.  Multiply the bounds.size by the scale to get the pixels.  You can think of unscaled values as being points, or virtual pixels.

Note that UIScreen has had a scale method since at least 3.2 but it has only been documented since 4.0 so respondsToSelector will trick you.  I check UIImage for scale even when I want to know about UIScreen.

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
CGFloat scale = [mainScreen scale];
CGRect bounds = [mainScreen bounds];
CGRect pixels = bounds;

if ( scale > 0 ) {
    pixels.origin.x *= scale;
    pixels.origin.y *= scale;
    pixels.size.width *= scale;
    pixels.size.height *= scale;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Any chance of answering my second question as well?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your second question about resolution, maybe this will help you.
From iOS4 and later there are pixels, points and scale factors.

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
```

[bounds will return points](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds) (480x320) not pixels (960x640).
[iOS4 Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10) (Points versus Pixels):

> In iOS 4 and later, the UIScreen,
>   UIView, UIImage, and CALayer classes
>   expose a scale factor that tells you
>   the relationship between points and
>   pixels for that particular object.
>   Before iOS 4, this scale factor was
>   assumed to be 1.0, but in iOS 4 and
>   later it may be either 1.0 or 2.0,
>   depending on the resolution of the
>   underlying device. In the future,
>   other scale factors may also be
>   possible.

Comment: I m gettin the scale whole tme as 0 in simulator.. any comments?